# adding json to httprequest

Tags: c#, rest, http-headers, azure-sql-database

I am using Sql Database rest api via c# code.
I am looking for a way to added the json to the body.
This is the format required.

```
{
    "properties": 
    {
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.3",
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.3"
    }
}
```

link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/firewallrules/createorupdate
I'n not so used to doing this type procedure. 
So, do I need to add the root 'properties' in the call? If so, how do I nest the json into the code?

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        startIpAddress = ip,
        endIpAddress = ip
    });

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
```

I tried this, but got bad format error back.
Many thanks in advance
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the required output json you should have something link this as your anonymous object:

```
new
{
     properties = new {
                        startIpAddress = ip,
                        endIpAddress = ip
                      }
}
```

Now it would have the properties as main object and inside it two properties that you need.